# How to transform text such that each output line starts with the block's title?

Tags: shell-script

I need to make a script to transform the following:

```
Name = x:y
Z =  a:b.c
Z1 = a1:b1.c1
End
Name=x1:y1
Z2 = a2:b2.c2
Z3 = a3:b3.c3
Z4 = a4:b4.c4
End
Name = l:k
s = w:e.v
End
```

into:

```
x:y Z    a:b.c
x:y Z1   a1:b1.c1
x1:y1   Z2   a2:b2.c2
x1:y1   Z3   a3:b3.c3
x1:y1   Z4   a4:b4.c4
l:k s    w:e.v
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `=` with optional surrounding whitespace as the delimeter:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*' '
    $1 == "Name" {name = $2; next}
    $1 != "End"  {print name, $1, $2}
' filename
```

#### Example

When looking at these `awk` solutions it can get a little confusing what's going on. If you insert some well placed print statements you can start to see in a visual fashion what's going on:

```
$ awk -F '[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*' '
      $1 == "Name" { name = $2; print "--NAME: "$2; next }; 
      $1 != "End" { print " --END: "name,$1,$2 }
' sample.txt
```

Which produces the following output:

```
--NAME: x:y
 --END: x:y Z a:b.c
 --END: x:y Z1 a1:b1.c1
--NAME: x1:y1
 --END: x1:y1 Z2 a2:b2.c2
 --END: x1:y1 Z3 a3:b3.c3
 --END: x1:y1 Z4 a4:b4.c4
--NAME: l:k
 --END: l:k s w:e.v
```

Comment: @ahmed That's a capital `F`. Copy and paste the command, don't re-type it, except for your file name.

Comment: i need to understand what is meaning by '[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*'

Comment: `[:blank:]` is a POSIX bracket expression http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html. It means tab or space, and because it is followed by `*` it means `zero or more tabs or spaces`. The full `'[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*` will match `=` or ` = ` and so forth (with many or no tabs and spaces around the equals sign).

Answer (score 1):

#### A way using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

This little `sed` command may do the job:

```
sed -ne '
  /^Name */{
    s/^.*= *//;
    h;
    tb;
  };
  /^End/bb;
  G;
  s/^\(.*\) *= *\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\3\t\1\t\2/p;
  :b
  ' <sourcefile.txt 
x:y Z       a:b.c
x:y Z1      a1:b1.c1
x1:y1       Z2      a2:b2.c2
x1:y1       Z3      a3:b3.c3
x1:y1       Z4      a4:b4.c4
l:k s       w:e.v
```

Explained:

- If a line begin by *Name*, drop until *=*, than store them to `hold space` and jump to label `:b`.
- If a line begin by *End*, skip next step until label `:b`.
- Before label `:b` (if else): Add `hold space`, than **if** the line match `string, followed by any number of spaces and an equal sign, some spaces maybe, a second string, a newline and finally a third string, **then** print third string, followed by a tab, first string a tab and then second string.

#### And a way using only [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
while read line ;do
    if [ ${line//=*} = "Name" ] ;then
        name=${line//*=}
    else
        [ "${line//=*}" != "$line" ] &&
            printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" $name ${line//=}
    fi
  done <sourcefile.txt 
x:y Z       a:b.c
x:y Z1      a1:b1.c1
x1:y1       Z2      a2:b2.c2
x1:y1       Z3      a3:b3.c3
x1:y1       Z4      a4:b4.c4
l:k s       w:e.v
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's Perl:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^Name\s*=\s*(.+)/){$n=$1;}else{print "$n $_" unless /^End/}' file
```

EXPLANATION

`perl -ne` means process the input file line by line (`-n`), saving each line into the variable `$_` and run the script given as a parameter to `-e`.

`if(/Name\s*=\s*(.+)/){$n=$1;}` : if the line starts with `Name = <something>`, save `<something>` as `$n`.

Else, if the line does not start with `Name`, print the current value of `$n`, the name and the rest of the line, unless that line is `End`.